# Will Apple TV from Canada work in Europe (Norway)?

Tags: appletv

I am moving to Europe (Norway) soon but I am considering to buy and Apple TV in Canada because it's cheaper.

I'm not worried about power outlet compatibility since I can just use an adapter, but does anyone know if the Apple TV from Canada will be fully functional in Norway, or will certain services, Apple accounts, etc. be restricted?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you also have a Canadian iTunes account?

Comment: The Apple TV has a universal power supply so you will just need to get the correct cable for Norway, no need for an adapter. They are very standard cables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apple TV functionality is almost entirely tied to your Apple ID. I believe the Apple ID "nationality" is tied to the billing address and/or credit card on file. If the address is Canadian, you'll have access to the Canadian iTunes and App stores, if it's Norwegian, you'll get the Norwegian stores. You can [use iTunes gift cards purchased in a given country to buy content on that country's stores](http://www.ilounge.com/index.php/articles/comments/purchasing-an-itunes-gift-card-for-use-in-another-country/), but switching back and forth between two countries seems to be problematic (you may only get access to the content from one country at a time, and it requires two billing addresses, or two iTunes accounts).

Apple has a few useful articles you may want to look at, including the [types of content available in each country](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3599), the [availability of iTunes Match and iTunes in the Cloud](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5085) (which allows you to re-download purchased content on a Mac or iOS device) and [whether you can buy or rent Movies and TV Shows](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3069).

From the looks of it, the content and options available in the Canadian store is superior to that of the Norwegian store (e.g. Norway doesn't have any TV shows), so if it's logistically feasible for you, it may be worthwhile to set up your iTunes account with a Canadian address and credit card (or just buy a lot of iTunes credit in Canada).